# How to write mockito test for spring boot server initializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

Can someone tell me how to write `mockito` test for `ServletInitializer`?

```java
package com.home.service.project.HomeServiceProject;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(HomeServiceProjectApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: The launcher (whether the `ServletInitializer` or `main`) is not customarily tested. The usual best practice is "make it too simple to test". (And use embedded instead of war if you have the option at all.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* write the following unit test to ensure `SpringApplicationBuilder` is called with the correct source class and the method returns the same instance you pass to `configure`.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
//@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) for JUnit 4
class ServletInitializerTest {

  @Mock
  private SpringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder;

  @Test
  public void testIt() {
    ServletInitializer servletInitializer = new ServletInitializer();
    when(springApplicationBuilder.sources(HomeServiceProjectApplication.class)).thenReturn(springApplicationBuilder);

    SpringApplicationBuilder result = servletInitializer.configure(springApplicationBuilder);

    verify(springApplicationBuilder).sources(HomeServiceProjectApplication.class);
    assertEquals(springApplicationBuilder,result);
  }

}
```

I would still question how valuable this unit test is and rather try to find a proper way to write an integration test to boot your whole application at least once to see everything is working together.